# selection of future date records from mysql database table

Tags: php, mysql, date, futuretask

[image]

Architecture of my table is as following:

[image]

I have the above table, wherein date datatype filed "l_from", i want to select all those records which having today date or all the future date from now.

For this i have used the following queries:

```
SELECT emp_sno,emp_type,l_from,l_to,l_nature 
FROM leaves_history 
WHERE l_from < CURDATE() AND emp_type = 1
```

But the above query does not help.
I have changed the

```
where l_from >= curdate()

where l_from <= curdate()
```

but in no clause return the highlighted row.

What should i have to change in?

thanks in advance

Comment: What's the data type of the column `l_from`?

Comment: data type of l_from column is : date

Comment: Also could you provide the table architecture, like which kinds of types dit you select for which columns.. You can achieve this by running a 'DESCRIBE leaves_history`

Comment: I have attached Architecture  of my table in the second image.

Comment: What is the value of `SELECT CURDATE();`? I ran a test and was unable to reproduce your issue.

Comment: CURDATE() return the required value of date but it also does not shows me the answer result. I just ran a testing query like this and i found it responsive:  SELECT emp_sno,emp_type,l_from,l_to,l_nature FROM leaves_history WHERE '".date('Y-m-d')."' BETWEEN l_from AND l_to AND emp_type = 1

Comment: I understand `SELECT CURRDATE();` returns a date, what date does it return exactly?

Comment: CURDATE() returns 2014-05-06 value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a go?

```
SELECT emp_sno,emp_type, l_from, l_to, l_nature 
FROM leaves_history 
WHERE l_from <= NOW() AND emp_type = 1
```

**EDIT Changed <= to >=**

```
SELECT emp_sno,emp_type, l_from, l_to, l_nature 
FROM leaves_history 
WHERE l_from >= DATE(NOW()) AND emp_type = 1
```

Comment: NOW() function returns yyyy-yy-yy h:m:s while i have "date" datatype

Comment: in that case you can use the DATE() function around the NOW().. but now should work, regardless of it's return type. See Edited Answer.

Comment: I used it in the query at first and the result was date(Now()) is very good. but the returned result was not accurate.

Comment: Well I'm assuming you want the results leading form NOW() into the future.. So you will need to change the operand. See edited Answer.

Comment: I guess, the record which it return will be from the now() year, I will not return the the data if 1_from year will be from next year.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your problem is not the query? But anyway this would work:

```
SELECT
  emp_sno,
  emp_type,
  l_from,
  l_to,
  l_nature
FROM leaves_history
WHERE l_from >= CURDATE()
    AND emp_type = 1
ORDER BY l_from
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this :

```
SELECT emp_sno,emp_type,l_from,l_to,l_nature
FROM leaves_history
WHERE l_from >= '2014-05-05'
AND emp_type = 1
```

where 2014-05-05 is current date